# Multilingual translation - open source framework?

Tags: database, multilingual

Are there any open source framkework to help with management of content for language translation? Like users can select their language of choice, system will pull in all untranslated text for that language, user can enter their translations, wait for 3-4 other people to verify it then push it live. Similar to facebook translation application. Looking for something I can implement with PHP. IF nothing is out there I will need to build one tool in-house for this. Any suggestions on the basic schema design to store languages in then?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Pootle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pootle)? It's

> an online translation management tool
>   with translation interface. It is
>   written in the Python programming
>   language using the Django framework
>   and is free software

...

> It can play various roles in the
>   translation process. The simplest
>   displays statistics for the body of
>   translations hosted by the server. Its
>   suggestion mode allows users to make
>   translation suggestions and
>   corrections for later review, thus it
>   can act as a translation specific bug
>   reporting system. It allows online
>   translation with the assignment of
>   work to various translators and lastly
>   it can operate as a management system
>   where translators translate using an
>   offline tool and use Pootle to manage
>   the workflow of the translation.

Might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this question for the last couple months since we've decided to adapt a PHP CMS to a more multilingual project. If you need some kind of backend translation workflow system, Poodle with the Translate Toolkit looks like the strongest solution, but it requires learning Django/Python framework.  This [screencast from Mozilla](http://l10n.mozilla.org/pootle/screencasts/mozilla-pootle.ogv) was helpful for me. Depending on your level of commitment and time constraints, this is not a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Google translate](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) has a php api

Comment: I am looking for in-house solutions, no external API as this is a social network and there is tons of content to tanslate in many many languages. Basically looking to create something similar to facebook translate application with added features. I can create it in shouse from scratch too once I figure out the basic schema of how the data can be stored. It is easy for system content but user content is a pain to keep track and manage as ppl can keep editing parts of some sentence.